# Where does Delphi store directory and conditional-define settings for a project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

In which file will the "Project-->Options-->Directories/Conditions" details get stored? Is it in build.dat or in project_name.dof?

Comment: I know the question is specifically for Delphi 5, but just a note, later versions of Delphi (2007 and up?) store this in the `.dproj` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea where you find a build.dat but configuration details get stored

- in your `.dof` file
- in a `.cfg` for command line compilation.

Look [here](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions) for a complete list of all extensions used in a Delphi project.

Comment: thanks.. I we change the options from IDE then it will automatically update the .cfg?

Comment: one more thing. If I dont have .dof and I am having only .cfg and then open a project then it will take the settings from .cfg? Because in my case I am having only .cfg and when I open project then it take the settings of the project which I opened previously.

Comment: @Naren - I can't verify it at the moment but if memory serves me well, there should be a template `.dof` file in your Delphi installation folder. I believe that's the one that get's used if you don't have a `.dof` file for your project but I find it strange you don't have one after saving a project.

Comment: I am working on the module which is developed by another guy and he hve not checked in the .dof file. :( any way to create it from .cfg?

Comment: Appart from opening it in notepad and copying it, not that I know of no *(but that doesn't mean anything:)*

Comment: :) :) i guess have no option other than that.. thanks for comments n help.

Comment: @Naren, from the helpfile "The compiler searches for a dcc32.cfg in the compiler executable directory, then for dcc32.cfg in the current directory, and then finally for projectname.cfg in the project directory.". The content of .cfg consists of dcc32.exe compiler settings and options. You can have alook of their meaning by typing dcc32 from the command prompt. The content of .cfg has their corresponding value in .dof file. Just create an empty project & save it. Open side by side those files, and you will see what I meant.

Comment: For example, in .cfg an option "-$A8" has a corresponding value "A=8" under [Compiler] section in .dof. Another example, "-$M16384,1048576" in .cfg has corresponding values "MinStackSize=16384" and "MaxStackSize=1048576" in .dof file.